# Resize images when height of browser changes

Tags: image, resize, height

I've made the following website using Bootstrap to get my images responsive. When resizing in width the images are perfectly responsive. However, when resizing in height, the images don't resize.

What would be the best way to get this working?

http://bartoosterveer.nl/Jacowebtest/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works the responsiveness with the width, It assumes the height will have no relevance since you can scroll... if you want your images to resize width the height, but keeping the same width, it might distort the quality of the image.

Now, as for how to do It the only way I can think of right now is implementing some media Queries for some heights.

i.e:

```
@media (min-height: xxx px) and (max-height: xxx px)
{
     #imageID
     {
        height: the height you desire for this range;
     }
 }
```

hope it helps